# Incorrect case-sensitive module name not detected at compile-time

Tags: elixir

My code is as follows:

```
  def ping(servoId) do
    Utilities.check_integer!(servoId,0,1,Error.const_error_servo_id())
    Genserver.call(@name,{:ping,servoId})
  end
```

The compiler doesn't give error message. But at the runtime, the message is as follows, Why? :

```
iex(3)> Mechanics.Servo.ping(1)

03:41:01.629 [error] Loading of /Users/yuchen/homebrew/Cellar/elixir/1.13.4/bin/../lib/elixir/ebin/Elixir.Genserver.beam failed: :badfile

 
03:41:01.629 [error] beam/beam_load.c(158): Error loading module 'Elixir.Genserver':
  module name in object code is 'Elixir.GenServer'


** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Genserver.call/2 is undefined (module Genserver is not available)
    Genserver.call(Mechanics.Servo, {:ping, 1})
```

Comment: Because I'm not able to see the full `Servo` module, I could only guess you didn't `use GenServer` at the top of your module.

Comment: This seems like a bug in Elixir though. Also interestingly, `h Genserver` in IEx crashes with a different error than a non-existing module.

Comment: This bug actually concerns any module: `StrinG.upcase "foo"` doesn't raise any compile warning but crashes at runtime. It seems some of the resolution ignores the case, for example `Code.fetch_docs(StrinG)` works.

Comment: I have add `use GenServer` already, and if I have change `Genserver` to `GenServer`, the error will disapppear. If it is bug, it seams  good news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in Elixir](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/12006) which happens when the filesystem is case-insensitive (e.g. macOS).

This is because the underlying `:code` module from Erlang looks up and finds the beam file on the filesystem:

```elixir
iex> :code.get_object_code(Genserver)
{Genserver, <<...>>, '.../lib/elixir/ebin/Elixir.Genserver.beam'}
```